# Error loading custom module listing page

Tags: magento2, module

In listing page from a custom module, i got this error when load more than 50 results.

> Attention
>
> Something went wrong.
>
> Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have
>   restored the filter to its original state.

If i show no more than 50 results, it works.

In my local does not happens the error.

php.ini
memory_limit    756M
max_input_vars  1000000

**Magento ver. 2.2.3**

Comment: Please show your custom module code. It's easier for us to debug your issue.